# What to do with Yocto build files once complete

Tags: linux

I am trying to learn how to use Yocto. After a successful build of an Intel Edison image, I see all the files in the output directory, but I don't know where to go from here (ie All the hard stuff should be done, now I just need to flash the Intel Edison with this image). There does not seem to be any documentation on next steps anywhere either. Can someone please point me in the right next direction?

Here is the output after the successful Yocto Intel Edison image build:

[image]

I'm confused because none of the files seem to match up with what you normally drop in the Edison storage. Just a little confused on what is needed (All, just one image, some files, etc?) and where to drop them in order to flash the Edison. Intel's documentation is still lacking quite a bit.

Thanks for the help

*** UPDATE ***

Ok, I got a little bit of help from Intel. Once finished compiling the image, these images are stored in the edison-src/build/tmp/deploy/images directory (screenshot I previously included). All thats left is to run this script: ./edison-src/device-software/utils/flash/postBuild.sh The files to flash to the Edison are stored in: ./edison-src/build/toFlash

Now all I am trying to figure out is how to run the flashall.sh or flashall.bat file. The batch file does not appear to be working on Windows, and I don't have a local Linux box at the moment to connect the Edison to in order to run the .sh script. I assume the Edison needs to be connected directly to the a Linux box, mount the flash in a specific way and run the flashall.sh script. Will do a bit more research and see if I can maybe spin up a VM to test. Any suggestions or input are welcomed and appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here, as Super User doesn't deal with programming questions (with expections for some bash scripting and Excel macros). I'm voting to migrate it to Stack Overflow. By the way, what's in the README?

Comment: Hmm, I disagree. This shouldn't have anything to do with programming. This is about flashing an embedded device with an image. No programming involved. The readme just contained a warning not to delete any files in that directory or I would have to clean stuff up and re compile the build. That readme does not apply to the question at hand.

Comment: Flashing an embedded device is an integral part of the process of programming it. At the same time, it's not something that a regular end-user would do. (Well, maybe with a router or something like that, but definitely not with Edison. It's a device for programmers, not for super users.) But it's just my opinion and I may be wrong.

Comment: True, however there is no code per se so it seems posting to stack overflow would be pointless. I could be wrong too, but I associate StackOverflow with programming language logic and syntax help. This issue to me was more of an administrative action. Probably more on the advanced side too though.

Comment: This question seems perfectly on-topic to me - it doesn't look too different from asking how to cross-compile and install a kernel on an ARM device.